# How can a determine if a plugin has been registered or not, given a HapiJS server object?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, hapi.js, hapi

I have code that loads a plugin dynamically based on environment.
Because I am using `jest --coverage`, and 100% coverage is required, I need to test if the plugin was loaded or not given the environment conditions set in the NODE_ENV.

All I am looking for here is how to determine if a particular plugin has been registered or not, after I compose the server object with `Glue()` and a manifest file that has logic to include the plugin only when `NODE_ENV` is not `"production"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is trying to figure this out, here is what I ended up doing:

```
describe('GIVEN NODE_ENV is production', () => {
    describe('WHEN service is initialized', () => {
        let server;
        const OLD_ENV = process.env;

        beforeEach(async () => {
            jest.resetModules();
            process.env = { ...OLD_ENV };
            process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
            server = await initialize();
        });

        afterEach(async () => {
            process.env = OLD_ENV;
            await server.stop();
            server = null;
        });

        test('THEN swagger plugin should not be added', () => {
            expect(server.registrations['hapi-swagger']).not.toBeDefined();
        });

    });
});
```